# How to trigger rabbit mq shutdown signal for testing?

Tags: java, rabbitmq, messagebroker, rabbitmq-exchange

Faced an issue on prod system where 1 message was left unacked for 30 mins which lead to consumer being shutdown. Now I have added shutdownlisteners as described in rabbit mq docs -
https://rabbitmq.github.io/rabbitmq-java-client/api/4.x.x/com/rabbitmq/client/ShutdownListener.html

```
                if (cause.isHardError()) {
                    log.error("Connection error with cause : {}", cause);
                    Connection conn = (Connection) cause.getReference();
                    if (!cause.isInitiatedByApplication()) {
                        Method reason = cause.getReason();
                        log.error("Rabbit Mq Consumer Connection Shutdown : {} {}", reason, cause);
                    }
                } else{
                    Channel ch = (Channel)cause.getReference();
                    log.error("Channel error details : {}", ch);
                }
            });
```

The issue is it's not getting invoked at all in testing. I tried triggering it through 2 ways-

1. Through unacked delivery timeout. Basically threw a general excption and never acked it(these were the original conditions of the bug). However, this didn't work.
2. I used channel.close() to shutdown the consumer but still didn't receive an event.

Looking for any way to replicate the issue I faced and test/trigger the shutdownlisteners. Thanks

Comment: Version 4.x.x of the Java client is out-of-date and no longer supported. The current version supports automatic consumer recovery.

Comment: Automatic recovery isn't triggered in all cases though? Also, this should be 5.5.3. Its only the api link that happens to be 4.x.x

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I can ask the maintainer of the Java client to assist us if you ask your question [here](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-java-client/discussions). Please provide as much code as possible, ideally something we can compile and run.

Answer (score 0):

I know this might be a late answer, but I've found an easy way is to keep the consumer connected to the rabbitmq broker and just drop my internet connection manually for a few seconds and reconnect.

After that the `shudown handler` is triggered.